# GAE Datastore (Golang): Filter Query When Adding New DB Field

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm running a GAE Golang application that's working with `datastore`. I have a struct which translates to a DB model on `datastore`, and I have added a new field to the struct, call it `NewField` (type `string`)

Existing instances ("rows" in the DB) for this struct have this `NewField` missing of course, which is expected.

I'm looking to create a query that will return all instances with where this `NewField` is missing (the existing instances).

This is what I tried:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("MyModel")
q = q.Filter("NewField =", "")
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that you can't.

Every query on GAE Datastore operates on an index. Since you just added the new property, existing entities without that property will not be in any indices (that includes that property). What you would need is to loop over entities *with no index records*, but that is not possible.

Your best bet is to query *all* entities, and do the filtering / update manually in Go code, where the `NewField` field has the zero value. Once you re-save existing entities, the new property will get indexed, and you will be able to search / filter by that property in the future.

If by any chance your entities store the creation time or last updated time (in a property), then you may use that: filter by last updated time to list only entities where the timestamp is less than the time when you added the new property to your Go model.

Another option (for future changes) is to add a `"version"` property to your entities. Whenever you perform a model update, increment the version for new entities. And you can always query entities with old versions (or with a specific version).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A bit lame on the datastore's behalf, product-wise, but I'll work around this.

Comment: @orcaman Agree, this may cause headaches, but on the other hand this is to ensure that all queries run "super fast" regardless of how many entities you have. And that is done by allowing only queries which are backed by indices. And such queries to list entities with missing properties, there is no index for that.